# Google Register/login using swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-signin

I'm new in swift.
 I'm working on app. In the app there is profile section. In which user can change there password after login.

User can login with Google/Facebook/LinkedIn or login with app. But if user login with Google/Facebook/LinkedIn then i want hide change password option from profile section.

Comment: What exactly are you asking and what have you tried so far? Please share your current effort.

Comment: Please have a read on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It should improve your chances to get an answer and avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

use `alpha`
set in your recognizer/function when user press Google/Facebook/Linkedln

```
changePassword.alpha = 0
```

to get it back to normal

```
changePassword.alpha = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.

You have a normal login button and Google/Facebook/LinkedIn buttons.
On your loginpageviewcontroller, simply add this

```
struct loginType 
{
 static var normalLogin = false
}
```

On pressing your '*login with app*' app button,

```
//inside button action add this
loginType.normalLogin = true
```

Now on the page that has '*change password option*', on viewDidLoad add this

```
if loginpageviewcontroller.loginType.normalLogin == true
{
changePasswordButton.isHidden = true
}
else
{
changePasswordButton.isHidden = false
}
```

On logout function add this

```
loginpageviewcontroller.loginType.normalLogin = false
```

This is the easiest way to do this, it requires a few more lines of code than a normal way but this is much more simple !